# how can I greyout a disabled field?

Tags: css, jsf-2

Might not be a JSF issue but JSF experts would know this possibly more
I have some fields on the form that are getting enabled disabled based on some ajax requests . I want to show them greyed out when disabled.

Let me know you need to see code but just using simple

```
<f:ajax event="keydown" execute="@this" render="field1 field2" />
```

field 1 the has

```
disabled="#{not empty someBean.someProperty}"
```

CSS is

```
#content input .disabled {color: #DCDAD1; padding: 2px; margin: 0 0 0 0;background-image=""}
```

Disabling itself is working fine but not getting greyed out

Thanks and applogies if JSF tag is not correct tag

Comment: I've never used JSF but do you need to remove the space between `input` and `.disabled` in the css selector?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The JSF input component's `disabled` attribute doesn't emit a style class like `class="disabled"` or something like as your CSS declaration seems to expect. It just sets the HTML-standard `disabled` attribute on the generated HTML element. To see it with your own eyes, open the JSF page in your favourite browser, rightclick and *View Source*. It'll look something like

```html
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" />
```

You need to use the CSS attribute selector `element[attrname]`. If the attribute with `attrname` is present on the `element`, then the style will be applied.

```css
#content input[disabled] {
    color: #DCDAD1;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    background-image: none;
}
```

*(please note that I fixed the `background-image` declaration as well as it was invalid)*

Comment: I'm using FF34 and it seems you need to use background-color instead of color now?

Comment: Is `#DCDAD1` color the universal color for a greyed out item?

Comment: @ayjay: nope, I just took over the color from the question.