# JSF textfield disabled does not work

Tags: jsf

I have a form in my xhtml page, and I want one of the textboxes to be disabled. Here is my code:

```
<h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="4" border="1">
            <h:outputText value="User Name: "></h:outputText>
            <h:inputText id="tUserName" disabled="disabled" value="#{user.customer.username}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

But this texbox is not disabled. If I use normal html form instead of JSF form it works but I want to do it this way. How can I make it look disabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `disabled="disabled"` to `disabled="true"`

Also you can use this [tag reference](http://www.developersbook.com/jsf/jsf-tags-reference/html/inputText.php) when you're unsure

Comment: Thanks that works, but the color of the texbox is not grey, it would be better if it was gray to indicate it is disabled can i do it?

Comment: @bigO Actually you know what here from the master himself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224604/how-can-i-greyout-a-disabled-field